# Finding covariance?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I had the following question to work through but can't get my answer to match the answer my teacher has given.

> Suppose that the bivariate random variable $(X,Y)$ has the joint density function:
>
> $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\left\{
>  \begin{array}{ll}
>   1  & \mbox{when } y > 0 , x+y<1 \text{ and } y<x+1 \\
>   0 & \mbox{otherwise }
>  \end{array}
> \right.$$
>
> Find $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$.

We have the same steps, integrating $(xy)$ over a double integral, and the same $x$ limits but our $y$ limits for the integral are different. He has integrated from $1$ to $-1$ with respect to $y$ but I can't understand why it isn't just between $1$ to $0$ for $y$.

Where has the $-1$ come from?

Comment: Seems like something is missing from the question. Or what does "x+y<1 and y" mean (especially the "and y" part)?

Comment: sorry edited it now, hope this makes more sense

Comment: @kay You're right, Note that when $y<0$, $f=0$, so it doesn't affect the integration. However, check and see if he intended to integrate with respect to $x$.

Comment: We both integrated between (1-y) and (1+y) with respect to x

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right. It's usually quite useful to draw the domain. If you haven't done that, [you can follow this link to see what it looks like.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%3E0,%20x%2by%3C1,%20y%3Cx%2b1) The limits one should integrate over are 
$$
0<y<1\\
y-1<x<1-y
$$
if $y$ is chosen for the outer integral.